# Is there evidence of people moving east to Europe?

Tags: europe, immigration, migration, arctic

We know that the Inuits moved from present-day Alaska to Greenland, but did they move any farther east? At least to Iceland or the other Nordic countries?

They would have to cross the Atlantic which wouldn't be the easiest, but the fact that they moved so quickly from Alaska to Greenland, makes me wonder whether they expanded any further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they didn't. There is no evidence of human occupation in Iceland before [Irish monks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceland#Settlement_and_Commonwealth_874%E2%80%931262) and later the Vikings settled there. Eskimo technology wasn't bad at all, kayaks are pretty nifty boats. But not suitable for migration.

Answer (score 3):

Well, they did, but not before they were discovered by europeans. Some inuits have moved to Denmark since Denmark had Greenland under their jurisdiction.